# python crawler code to search for any file on the web

Tags: python, web-crawler

is there a python crawler / web spider code to search for any file on the web based on a single or multiple search keywords? The code needs to search for a match of  maximum keywords within the file before return the link or downloading the file to a folder.

Comment: Really too broad, but I think you can try to implement something basic by yourself, with the http library, and the xml library to parse the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should try python scrapy. https://scrapy.org/ The documentation is really good and you can do a lot with the examples.